# Abstract Inheriting form of Comparable Interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract, comparable

I understand how to use the `Comparable<T>` interface, but in this specific example, I'm wondering if there is a way to require the inheriting Class from an Abstract Class *(which implements the `Comparable<T>` interface)* to be Comparable against itself.

Let me reiterate, there is an Abstract Class that implements the Comparable Interface:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass implements Comparable<MyAbstractClass>
```

And a Class which inherits from this Abstract Class:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass
```

Typically with this setup, the following method is required to satisfy the Comparable Interface:

```
public int compareTo(MyAbstractClass otherAbstractObject)
```

This requires me to make the following cast:

```
public int compareTo(MyAbstractClass otherAbstractObject)
{
    MyClass otherObject = (MyClass) otherAbstractObject;

    // Comparison...
    return result;
}
```

Given the fact that this cast could easily fail by trying to use a different child of `MyAbstractClass`, I would like to be able to define my Abstract Class to accept the following method:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass otherMyObject)
{
    // Comparison...
    return result;
}
```

And ideas on how to accomplish this? Or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `MyAbstractClass` using generics as follows:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends MyAbstractClass<T>>
    implements Comparable<T> {
```

Then you can define subclasses such as

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyClass>
```

which allow you to define the `compareTo` method like this:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass otherMyClass)
```

However, that doesn't prevent anyone from writing a subclass that doesn't conform to the pattern:

```
public class SneakyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyClass>
```

which would also define the `compareTo` method similarly:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass otherMyClass)
```

Note: There's nothing that can force the generic type parameter of a class to equal the class on which it's defined; the best you can do is to enforce an upper bound on the abstract class, to at least force it to be some kind of `MyAbstractClass`.